# In what file(s) are the drupal-6 custom blocks found?

Tags: drupal, authentication, drupal-6

I accidentally added a login block which somehow overrides the origin User Login built in block from drupal. I need to delete the block, the drupal login is frozen and I cannot access the usual admin menu interface to change it. Where is it in the mysql database?

I could not find any amendment to the block module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you ask question related to Drupal, please mention version.

Anyway...you will find block table in DB whether it's 6 or 7, so browse that and sort it by PRIMARY-Descending, you will see your last setting which you have done at first. Delete that and you will go back to one step...

But if you have done some more setting with block after that then record must have gone some far..

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I landed up deactivating the blocks by mistake, by deleting a number of the logged changes in the Blocks mysql table, and had to manually log in using the URL ...?q=user/login and then .../admin to redefine the blocks positioning.  (ALSO, edited the question title).

Comment: also deleting the block log did not delete the new blocks I had made; they must be stored elsewhere, although i don't know where.

Comment: Did I say it would delete block ? By deleting that you would just delete the setting and you will be able to roll back one step and find your site working.. Then after you can delete from the list of block..isn't it ?